# Get the position of a CGRect in an Interface Builder file

Tags: xcode, cgrect

Instead of guessing the float points of a UI element on the screen, is there any tool to tell me the exact position of a UI element in my storyboard?

Comment: in the storyboard? or in the simulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you have taken a look at the *Utilities* section in Xcode. It is displayed on the right side. If it is not there, click on the third button of the View section

[image: View buttons]

And then you can find the ruler tab where you can see all the values of the CGRect you want: X, Y, width, and height.

[image: Utilites ruler]

PS: In addition to that, ff you want to see the CGRect values of the views on the fly in the Simulator, you can use [DCIntrospect](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect), which I find is really helpful for debugging. You can click on the views and see the CGRect values on the top right corner.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! "Frame Rectangle" was never accurate for me when I tried it in CGRect.